# How do I insert a variable in MXML (Flash builder 4)?

Tags: flash, variables, mxml, builder

I have a text box that receives data from XML. Has activated the service. Everything works fine if i use "taurus" instead myVar in {}. 
Now I want to change the field and depending on the button is pressed to receive different data. But nothing comes out.

> 

```
        public var myVar:String = "taurus";

        protected function t1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            getDataResult.token = lov.getData();
        }


        protected function b1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var myVar:String = "aries";
            getDataResult.token = lov.getData();
        }

    ]]>



</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:CallResponder id="getDataResult"/>
    <lov:Lov id="lov" fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString + '\n' + event.fault.faultDetail)" showBusyCursor="true"/>

</fx:Declarations>
<s:TextArea x="10" y="146" width="179" height="89" id="t1" text="{getDataResult.lastResult.myVar.yesterday}"/>
<s:TextArea x="10" y="257" width="179" height="89" id="t2" text="{getDataResult.lastResult.taurus.today}"/>

<s:Button x="10" y="27" label="Aries" id="b1" click="b1_clickHandler(event)"/>
```

Comment: You should rephrase your question - It's hard to understand what's your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what your question is, but are you trying to change a label in the UI based on the button click?  If so, you'll want to add [Bindable] above your declaration of myVar.

Answer (score 0):

If this another value suppose to be "aries", than you've been doing it wrong. You've defined new `myVar` variable where you should've only change its value.

This line defines new variable for the current scope:

```
var myVar:String = "aries";
```

This line changes the value of an existing variable:

```
myVar = "aries";
```

Comment: Oh, yes, you're right. But this does not solve the problem.
Thanks